# C++ only define specialisation of template member function

Tags: c++

I have the following class that maintains some global state:

```
struct StateController{

..
..
..

StateChanger1Inverse apply_state_changer(const StateChanger1Inverse& s1);
StateChanger2Inverse apply_state_changer(const StateChanger2Inverse& s1);
StateChanger3Inverse apply_state_changer(const StateChanger3Inverse& s1);   

return

}
```

i.e the apply change gives the inverse of the change (which in this case is always 1 to 1)

I thought of templating this to cut out some repeated code as follows:

```
struct StateController{

    ..
    ..
    ..
    template<class StateChange>
    typename StateChange::inverse_change apply_state_changer(const StateChange& s1);

}
```

for a StateChange object that must define inverse_change typedef:

i.e

```
struct StateChanger1{
    typedef StateChanger1Inverse inverse_change
     ..
    other stuff
}
```

Now, in my implementation file, I have only the specialisations of these member functions as the general case is meaningless, and consequently the ide is warning me that I have not defined the function. I should say that the code compiles just fine.

Is it acceptable to do this, and not define the general member function?

Comment: *"in my implementation file"*. template's places are in header in general.

Comment: Unclear what you do: template declaration doesn't match with non template code.

Comment: What is this `return` in class definition ?

Comment: edited, hopefully this is clearer